# Asp.net webforms UI testing tools

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, webforms, automated-tests

I would like to hear what web UI testing tools you have found to be useful and not so useful.

I am looking for a commercial tool (for the company) and a non commercial tool (for my projects)

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at these links :

http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/tools-aspnet-ui-testing

http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/

http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/AutomatedtestingofASPNETwebapplicationsusingSelenium.aspx

Answer (score 0):

NUnit is probably the most popular ASP.NET testing tool out there:

[www.nunit.org](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=community)

As it is open source, you can use it both at home and at work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using TestPlan. It has a scripting language which accomplishes most web testing tasks without too much effort. It is a free product with commercial support also available.

http://testplan.brainbrain.net/